# Group by/Aggregate Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a data frame like:

```
material plant   Order      m1  m2  m3  m4  m5
24990     89952 4568789     1.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
24990     89952 5098710     1.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
24990     89952 9448609     0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 1.0
24990     89952 1007081     0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 1.0
166621    3062  18364103    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
166621    3062  78309139    0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
240758    3062  55146035    1.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 0.0
276009    3062  38501581    1.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 0.0
276009    3062  38575428    1.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 0.0
```

I want to combine the Order number which has same material comabination in m1 to m5.

I want to achieve a dataframe something like:

```
material plant  Order                m1 m2  m3  m4  m5
24990   89952   4568789,5098710     1.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
24990   89952   9448609,1007081     0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 1.0
166621  3062    18364103            0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
166621  3062    78309139            0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
240758  3062    55146035            1.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 0.0
276009  3062    38501581,857542     1.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 0.0
```

I am trying something like :

```
Data frame x
y = x.values 
x['new_col'] = y.tolist() 
df1 = x['new_col'] df = df1.to_frame()
```

then trying to do df1.groupby with 'new_col'(which is m1to m5),but not getting what I want.
Do I have to use for loop?
   any help would be appreciatable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by all columns without `Order` with `join`, last add [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for columns from `MultiIndex` and [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for same ordering of columns:

```
c = df.columns.difference(['Order']).tolist()
df = (df.groupby(c, sort=False)['Order'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str)))
        .reset_index()
        .reindex(columns=df.columns))
print (df)
   material  plant              Order   m1   m2   m3   m4   m5
0     24990  89952    4568789,5098710  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1     24990  89952    9448609,1007081  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0
2    166621   3062           18364103  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
3    166621   3062           78309139  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4    240758   3062           55146035  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
5    276009   3062  38501581,38575428  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
```

Similar solution if need `list`s:

```
c = df.columns.difference(['Order']).tolist()
df = (df.groupby(c, sort=False)['Order'].apply(list)
        .reset_index()
        .reindex(columns=df.columns))
print (df)
   material  plant                 Order   m1   m2   m3   m4   m5
0     24990  89952    [4568789, 5098710]  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1     24990  89952    [9448609, 1007081]  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0
2    166621   3062            [18364103]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
3    166621   3062            [78309139]  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4    240758   3062            [55146035]  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
5    276009   3062  [38501581, 38575428]  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way. First define your columns, possibly using `numpy.r_` to extract the necessary indices of columns. Then `groupby` to list and `reset_index`.

```
group_cols = df.columns[np.r_[0:2, 3:len(df.columns)]].tolist()

res = df.groupby(group_cols)['Order'].apply(list).reset_index()
```

Result:

```
   material  plant   m1   m2   m3   m4   m5                 Order
0     24990  89952  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0    [9448609, 1007081]
1     24990  89952  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0    [4568789, 5098710]
2    166621   3062  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0            [18364103]
3    166621   3062  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0            [78309139]
4    240758   3062  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0            [55146035]
5    276009   3062  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  [38501581, 38575428]
```